# Calling a .NET Maui app to change a file name when saving

Tags: c#, winforms, maui

I have a .NET Maui application that generates QR codes and saves them to a specified file on the PC if it is a Windows platform after clicking a button:

```
    private void OnSaveClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
#if WINDOWS
        String path = "C:\\my\\file\\path\\QRCodeName.png";
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, qrCodeBytes);
```

I also have a C# Windows form app (.NET Framework). This form just has a text box and a button. I want to call my .NET Maui application to generate a QR code and then have the "QRCodeName.png" to be changed to what the user of this Windows form enters in its textbox once they click the button on that Windows form. Is this possible?

I have tried making the .NET Maui program an executional file and calling it with that button on the Windows form and changing the name of the QR code, but this is not working. I think it is because the QR code is generated when clicking a button in the .NET Maui app.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/

Comment: IPC is the first what comes in mind. But you can also extract qr-code functionality into dll (.net standard), then you can use it for all platforms. Actually there are several QR-code nugets around.

Comment: Put the logic of generating and saving QR code to separate C# library and it can be used in both apps MAUI/WinUI and WinForms